# Unix permissions needed when running Powershell script

Tags: powershell, unix, active-directory

As a final step in our AD account creation process that is being moved to a powershell script a few folders need to be created on the filer for users and I am coming unstuck with permissions.

I am just using the basic new-item command to create folder but the locations need unix permissions (775) set before anything can be created.  I can't go there and right click in Windows explorer and click new..   and the powershell script is being bounced also due to permissions.

The reasoning from one of the tech guys here is that I am trying to create a sub folder via smb mount from Windows using ntfs permissions.  There is no correlation to unix permissions and any of our Linux users won't be able to access / use the location created for them.

Sorry if that is a clumsy way of explaining it, I am not a systems engineer, just the guy trying to translate a whole heap if pearl scripts into a new powershell process.

Thank you

S.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What Unix permissions do you need to set? Where? And why do they have to be "Unix permissions" in the first place? What have you tried so far? What errors did that yield? Please [edit] your question and elaborate.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am guessing that he wants to modify the permissions of a folder in a Samba file share running on a Unix server remotely from a Windows machine.